# Matrix multiplication for autorotation and different screen sizes

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

Whether you use fixed or programmable shader pipeline, a common vertex pipeline consists of this matrix multiplication (either custom coded or behind the scenes):

```
Projection * Modelview * Position
```

Lots of tutorials note items such as an object's rotation should go into the `Modelview` matrix.

I created a standard rotation matrix function based on degrees and then added to the degrees parameter the proper multiple of 90 to account for the screen's autorotation orientation. Works.

For different screen sizes (different pixel widths and heights of screen), I could also factor a `Scale` multiplier in there so that a `Modelview` matrix might incorporate a lot of these.

But what I've settled on is a much more verbose matrix math and since I'm new to this stuff, I'd appreciate feedback on whether this is smart.

I simply add independent matrices for the screensize scaling as well as the screen orientation, in addition to object manipulation such as scale and rotation. I end up with this:

```
Projection * ScreenRotation * ScreenScale * Translate * Rotate * Scale * Position
```

Some of these are interchangeable order, such as `Rotate` and `Scale` could be switched, I find.

This gives me more fine-tuned control and segregation of code so I can concentrate on just an object's rotation without thinking of the screen's orientation at the same time, for example.

Is this is a common or acceptable strategy to organize matrix math appropriately? It seems to work fine, but are there any pitfalls to such verbosity?

Comment: Lookup *Concatenation of Transforms*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main issue with such verbosity is, that it wastes precious computation cycles if performed on the GPU. Each matrix would be supplied as a uniform, thus forcing the GPU into computing for each and every vertex, while it would be actually a constant across the whole shader. The nice thing about matrices is, that a single matrix can hold the whole chain of transformations and transformation can be done by a single vector-matrix multiplication.

The typical stanza

> ```
> Projection · Modelview · Position
> ```

of using two matrices comes from, that usually one needs the intermediary result of `Modelview · Position` for some calculations. In theory you could contract the whole thing down to

> ```
> ProjectionViewModel · Position
> ```

Now you're proposing this matrix expression

> Projection * ScreenRotation * ScreenScale * Translate * Rotate * Scale * Position

Ugh… this whole thing is the pinnacle of unflexibility. You want flexibility? This thing is **rigid**, what if you wat to apply some nonuniform scaling onto already rotated geometry. The order of operations in matrix math matters and you can not freely mix them. Assume you're drawing a sphere

```
Rotate(45, 0, 0, 1) · Scale(1,2,1) · SphereVertex
```

looks totally different than

```
Scale(1,2,1) · Rotate(45, 0, 0, 1) · SphereVertex
```

Screen scale and rotation can, and should be, applied directly into the Projection matrix, no need for extra matrices. The key understanding is, that you can compose **every** linear transformation chain into a single matrix. And for practical reasons you want to apply screen pixel aspect scaling as last step in the chain, and screen rotation as the second to last step in the chain.

So you can build your projection matrix, not in the shader, but in your display routines frame setup code. Assume you're using my linmath.h it would look like the following

```
mat4x4 projection;
mat4x4_set_identity(projection);
mat4x4_mul_scale_aniso(projection, …);
mat4x4_mul_rotate_Z(projection, …);
if(using_perspective)
    mat4x4_mul_frustum(projection, …);
else
    mat4x4_mul_ortho(projection, …);
```

The resulting matrix `projection` you'd then set as the projection matrix uniform.

Comment: Thank very much for your answer, I look forward to reading it in greater detail a bit later. This stuff is fascinating and also a bit steep on the learning.

Comment: I tested your suggestion with `ScreenScale * ScreenRotation *Projection *  Translate * Rotate * Scale * Position` to see how the ordering works, but this caused unequal scaling and my squares became rectangles. Is this the matrix order you suggested?

Comment: Perhaps your ordering is in fact what I already had (aside from the separate matrices)

Comment: @SebbyJohanns: This entirely depends on the semantics of the rest of the program. For example if your screen has rectangular pixels, then the screen aspect ratio is actually something to be considered in the Projection matrix and only a final rotation is to be applied. If however the screen pixels are anisotropic, like on some stereoscopic displays or old analogue television, the you need a post scaling. Most computer screens have quadratic pixels, though.

Comment: @SebbyJohanns: Essentially the ratio `(right-left)/(top-bottom)` of your projection matrix (either perspective frustum or ortho) should match your *viewing orientation's* screen aspect ratio. For for a 9:16 screen rotated by 90° the ratio of the projection should be 16:9 then.

Comment: I had successfully sent an ortho mult to the projection, but when I preceded the projection matrix with scale and rotation of the screen, it was distorted. The Projection (ortho) should be the last (first in the multiplication statment) transform applied, right? When you said in your answer `screen pixel aspect scaling` you were referring to the ortho?

Comment: @SebbyJohanns: No, I was referring to the situation, that your output device uses pixels that are not quadratic. If you're developing for an off-the-shelf computer this is most likely not the case. Say you got an Nexus7 screen (800x1280 in portrait mode), in landscape orientation. Then a matching projection setup would be `rotate_Z(90°) · ortho(-(1280./800.), (1280./800.), -1, 1, -1, 1)`

Comment: @SebbyJohanns: Unfortunately I don't have an iOS or Android SDK available right now, otherwise I'd write you up a small demo.

Comment: Thanks. To be clear, since transformations are actually applied in reverse order, the shader might show `ortho * rotate` in your example, right??

Comment: @SebbyJohanns: Only if you write it as this. It's not that transformations are applied "in reverse", the just go from right to left if written in the usual way.